# Typescript string manipulation not working

Tags: string, typescript

I have a ";" delimited string. I need to remove an entry from it. I tried to use slice but that does get sliced string but not the original-modified string.
Here is an example:

```
    var str1: string = 'TY66447;BH31496;PA99001;';

    var str2 = str1.slice(16, 23);

    console.log(str1);
    console.log(str2);
```

It gives:

```
TY66447;BH31496;PA99001;
PA99001
```

But what I want to achieve is TY66447;BH31496;
I am not sure if I am using the correct string method. Please guide how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you want, but it seems that you want:

```
str1.slice(0, 16);
```

Comment: I  have PA99001; value from an $event, so I find indexOf this value. It could be any item, even TY66447; or BH31496;. So basically, I have to remove the item from the string str1

Comment: All string manipulation functions slice, substring, substr do not modify original string, whereas, I need to modify original string. ideas?